# Get Podio Item via the SDK using ID from database and not from Podio

Tags: api, get, podio

I wrote an app that pushes items into Podio.
Now I need to update the Items in Podio, but we need a way to get the Item by using our data (eg. a Order Number or Product ID), because we have no way of tracking the ItemId that is given on Submit.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Podio API is returning `item_id` of newly created item in response, so it should be fairly easy to save that item_id together with your data (e.g. Order Number or Product ID).

Create item documentation is here, have a look on **Response** section 
https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/add-new-item-22362

Sample on Ruby:

```
content = {'title'=> 'sample item title'}
item = Podio::Item.create(app_id, 'fields' => content)
puts "item.item_id: #{item.item_id}"

Output:
> item.item_id: 9202803167
```

Once `item_id` is saved, you can use as much as you need to get item back from Podio API.

Comment: Since our Product ID is already a unique value, is it not possible to pass it through as the item_id?

Comment: Podio will generate new item_id for each item created. You can have an item_field (let's call it product_id) and then you can search by value in that field, but I dont think this is what you are looking for.